# how can i fix this currency converter for python?

Tags: debugging, syntax

I have made this code for a currency converter but it comes up with syntax. Please I am using python 3.3.2 .

```
currencynum = 0
yenpound=0.0059
yendoler=0.0098
yeneuro=0.0071
yenyen=1
yeneuro=0.0071
yenyen=1
poundyen=170.55
pounddoler=1.67
poundeuro=1.21
poundpound=1
dolpound=0.60
doleuro=0.73
doldol=1
dolyen=102.37
europound=0.83
eurodol=1.38
euroyen=140.79
euroeuro=1


tipe= input ("input what curontsy you have. yen y,us dollrus d, euro e, pound p.")
            if tipe == "y":
                print ("you have choson yen")

            elif tipe == "e":
                print("you have choson euro")

            elif tipe == "d":
                print ("you have choson us dollrus")

            elif tipe == "p":
                print ("you have choson pound")

            howmuch = float(input("how much do you have"))

            otheramount = input ("input what curontsy you want to convert. yen y,us dollrus, euro e, pound p.")

            if otheramount == "y":
                print ("you have choson yen")
            elif otheramount == "e":
                print("you have choson euro")

            elif otheramount == "us":
                print ("you have chosen us dollrus")

            elif otheramount == "p":
                print ("you have choson pound")


            if tipe == "y":


                   if otheramount == "y":
                       print ("yy")
                   currencynum=howmuch*yenyen
                   print (currencynum)

                   elif  otheramount == "e":
                       print ("ye")
                   currencynum=howmuch*yeneuro
                   print (currencynum)

                   elif otheramount == "d":
                       print ("yd")
                   currencynum=howmuch*pounddoler
                   print (currencynum)


                   elif otheramount == "p":
                       print ("yp")
                   currencynum=howmuch*yenpound
                   print (currencynum)


            elif tipe == "e":

                   if otheramount == "y":
                       print ("ey")
                   currencynum=howmuch*euroyen
                   print (currencynum)

                   elif otheramount == "e":
                       print ("ee")
                   currencynum=howmuch*euroeuro
                   print (currencynum)

                   elif otheramount == "d":
                       print ("ed")
                   currencynum=howmuch*eurodol
                   print (currencynum)

                   elif otheramount == "p":
                       print ("ep")
                   currencynum=howmuch*europound
                   print (currencynum)

            elif tipe == "d":

                   if otheramount == "y":
                       print ("dy")
                   currencynum=howmuch*dolyen
                   print (currencynum)

                   elif otheramount == "d":
                       print ("dd")
                   currencynum=howmuch*doldol
                   print (currencynum)

                   elif otheramount == "p":
                       print ("dp")
                   currencynum=howmuch*dolpound
                   print (currencynum)

                   elif otheramount == "e":
                       print ("de")
                   currencynum=howmuch*doleuro
                   print (currencynum)

            elif tipe == "p":

                   if otheramount == "y":
                       print ("py")
                   currencynum=howmuch*poundyen
                   print (currencynum)

                   elif otheramount == "p":
                       print ("pp")
                   currencynum=howmuch*poundpound
                   print (currencynum)

                   elif otheramount == "d":
                       print ("pd")
                   currencynum=howmuch*pounddoler
                   print (currencynum)

                   elif otheramount == "e":
                       print ("pe")
                   currencynum=howmuch*poundeuro
                   print (currencynum)


            #currency = tipe + otheramount

            #command=currency
            #total= howmuch *  currencynum
            #print (total)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Here you have a Hello. When using paired data name-value it is better to store it as a dictionary. What kind of error it says, normally it says something like in `line 42 error:
SyntaxError:....`. Have you tried to correct this line?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be from bad indentation..
You need about 4 spaces (don't know if this is version-related and sometimes need 6 or 8?) for each indentation then it'll work.
Remember that every new if-statement will require another indentation and that your multiplication should be inside the if-block so it has to be indented as well!